# How to Using '\r\n' inside the grid

Tags: c#, escaping

I wonder why '\r\n' doesn't apply in the grid. Note that \t applies.

```
spdTestList.ActiveSheet.Cells[i, spdTestList.ActiveSheet.Columns["TEST"].Index].Text = "DDD" +"\r\n"+ "FFF";
```

result : "DDDFFF"

desired result :  "DDD FFF"

Comment: What grid are you talking about?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use "DDD" + " " + "FFF"? Note that I added a space char in between two strings.

Comment: `"DDD" +" "+ "FFF";`

Comment: Have you tried to use  `"DDD" + Environment.NewLine + "FFF"` ? [Environment.NewLine Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: What exactly do you expect? That the cell displays a line break? Or that the cell shall display \r\n as space char?